# where do I instantiate my class so I can access it throughout my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I've been working through some objective-c/ iOS dev books and I've hit a stumbling block. I get the feeling that I'm missing something dumb here, so I'm sure you guys can help, because you're all so damn smart :-).

I've got a very simple app that consists of 1 button and 1 label. Pushing the button puts a message in the label. I've created a class that includes a method to create said message. Here is the problem:

```
#import "classTestViewController.h"

@implementation classTestViewController
@synthesize myLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


}

-(IBAction) pressGo:(id)sender{

    MyClass * classTester = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    classTester.count = 15;
    NSString *newText = [classTester makeString ]; 
    myLabel.text = newText;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [classTester release];
    [myLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The output of this app, in my label, is "Yay 15". So you can see the problem, the only way I can get this to work is to instantiate the class right there, in the "pressGo" method. This isn't desirable because another method can't access or change the class variable count. Also I get a warning that local declaration of classTester hides instance variable. If I move the class instantiation to the viewDidLoad method, which seems right, the other methods can't access it anymore.

#import "classTestViewController.h"

```
@implementation classTestViewController
@synthesize myLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   MyClass * classTester = [[MyClass alloc] init];


}

-(IBAction) pressGo:(id)sender{

    classTester.count = 15;
    NSString *newText = [classTester makeString ]; 
    myLabel.text = newText;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [classTester release];
    [myLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The output of that is nada. If I try to access just one variable, classTester.count, for example, even after setting it, I get a 0 value.  I also get the override warning here as well.

So my question is, how can i get access to that class instance throughout my app and not just in one method? I'm using a view based application.

Comment: If you're looking for a **singleton**, you need Gallagher's file which everyone uses for singletons. http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html.  Get the actual file here http://projectswithlove.com/projects/SynthesizeSingleton.h.zip.  Do not overuse singletons if you are a new programmer, you need to know what you are doing.  Read more about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `classTester` in your interface file with:

```
@class MyClass
@interface classTestViewController : UIViewController
{
    MyClass *classTester;
}
// Any other custom stuff here
@end
```

Then instantiate it in your viewDidLoad method with:

```
classTester = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

And you should be able to access the ivar from any method within this class. If you want it to be accessible to your entire app, @Waqas link will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Just be aware that `-viewDidLoad` can be called many times during a UIViewController's life. It is an appropriate place to create instance variable which are only needed while the view is visible (and which should therefore be released in `-viewDidUnload`) but if you want this `MyClass` instance to continue to store data when this `classTestViewController`'s view is not visible then you probably want to initialize `classTester` in the controller's designated initializer instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a singleton class which instantiate once and is available inside whole project

Have a look

http://projectcocoa.com/2009/10/26/objective-c-singleton-class-template/